# how to know whether it is default page or not from master page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I want to call one div when the page is default.aspx and to call same div at the same time when the page is another page than default.I have done something like this but is not doing correctly.

```
<% if(string.Compare(Request.Url.LocalPath,"/default.aspx")==0 ||  string.Compare(Request.Url.LocalPath,"/") ==0)
{%>
    <div class="temples" >
 <% } %>
<% else
{ %>
    <div class="temples" style="display:none";>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
string s = this.Page.Request.FilePath;
```

This will get you the current request URL from within the master page

Also check the [IsMasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.documentviewerbase.ismasterpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> Gets a value that indicates whether or not a child element in the
>   viewer should be used as a master page.

Comment: yes but can u say me now how to put that if else condition.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property **IsMasterPage** to define whether your control element associated to master page. Below is a link to get more information.

[DocumentViewerBase.IsMasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.documentviewerbase.ismasterpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)